# Problem with system of equations

Tags: quadratics, systems-of-equations

I wonder how to solve this system of equations:
$\begin{cases} 2x^2+y^2=43\\2x^2+4xy=78\end{cases}$

when I subtract I have $y(4x-y)=35$ but I don't if it is good way to look for the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding both the equations gives you :
$$4x^2 + 4xy + y^2 = 121$$
$$(2x+y)^2 = 121$$
You will get $y$ in terms of $x$ from this equation which you can substitute in the given equation, solve the quadratic equation, find $x$ and eventually $y$.

Comment: ohh indeed, I overlooked it thanks for help

Comment: @Gregor No problem.If you are completely satisfied with any answer, accept it so that it would let others know that this question is taken care of and they would not waste their time in posting another solution.